# Add class to active menu item

Tags: jquery

If user on frontpage add class "active" to first li, if on gallery page add class "active" to second li and so on...

```
<ul>
<li class="home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li class="gallery"><a href="/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
<li class="products"><a href="/products">Products</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can add in you first li class "active".

Comment: you need to get the current URL using javascript/jquery and based on the URL you need to add the active class to specific "li"

Comment: @Diplak yes, but how the code should look like, could you provide some?

Answer (score 5):

You can do like as below to make active your menu. (If you determine your URL content of particular page than below sample code may be helpful to you)

```
<ul id="ulMenu">
    <li class="home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="gallery"><a href="/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    <li class="products"><a href="/products">Products</a></li>
</ul>
```

Try below function in master page and modify the URL contains value in function.

```
function MakeActiveMenu()
{
    var currentURL = window.location.pathname;
    var allMenu = $("#ulMenu").find('li');

    if(allMenu != null){
       $.each(allMenu, function(index,value){
          value.classList.remove('active');
       });
    }

    if(currentURL != null){

      if(currentURL.toLowerCase().contains("Home")) {
         $('.home').addClass('active');
      }
      else if (currentURL.toLowerCase().contains("Gallery")){
         $('.gallery').addClass('active');
      }
      else if (currentURL.toLowerCase().toLowerCase().contains("Products")){
         $('.products').addClass('active');
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: not working. i modified it a little. what i made wrong, could you please check it? the page i'm trying to achive this [link](http://www.meegaste.ee/uus)

Answer (score 0):

You can either have your server side detect which is the "current" page, and render the "active" class to the right `li`, OR, use javascript to detect which is the current page, and add the class

jQuery code:

```
$('.gallery').addClass('active'); // for the 'gallery' page
```